# How to remove anaconda from windows?

Tags: anaconda, window

Setup aborted during anaconda installation. In order to reinstall, I have to erase the Anaconda file where the installation was interrupted.
However, uninstall-anaconda does not exist, perhaps because the installation was interrupted.

Is there any other way to remove anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

can you please check this  path `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2`  and check whether uninstall is present or not